# Inflating partial gzip content with pako?

Tags: javascript, zlib, pako

In node, zlib can be used to decompress partial gzip content (truncated). I tried the same with pako, but looks like it's not working.

This is what I tried:

```
const s = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x8bV23J15O4\xb14\xb1H61417KKLL\xb50L5U\x8a\x05\x00\xf6\xaa\x8e.\x1c\x00\x00\x00";

const truncated = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x8bV23J15O4\xb14\xb1H61417KKLL\xb50L5U\x8a\x05\x00\xf6\xaa\x8e.\x1c\x00\x00";  // doesn't work

const array = Uint8Array.from([...s].map(v => v.charCodeAt(0)));

var data        = pako.inflate(array);

var strData2     = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

console.log(strData2);
```

decompressing `s` works but when I try to decompress `truncated` i get an empty string.

**Update:**

tried also with the stream syntax, doesn't work:

```
const inflate = new pako.Inflate({ level: 3});
inflate.push(array, true);   // tried also false
```

Comment: There is a streaming inflator you can use instead. See https://nodeca.github.io/pako/#Inflate.new

Comment: @MarkAdler tried it, doesn't work. updated the question what i tried

Comment: Try with `false`, truncating the last eight bytes instead of the last one byte. You can also try feeding a byte at a time.

Comment: By the way, the `Inflate.new` example on that page makes on sense. They copied it from the `Deflate.new` example. There is no `level` parameter when inflating. And of course the data they are feeding it in the example can't be inflated.

Comment: Note that you should be able to get the intermediate data with `Inflate#onData`.

Comment: @MarkAdler sadly, nothing works... http://jsfiddle.net/4qau3e6o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `const inflate = new pako.Inflate({chunkSize: 1});`. That delivers every byte as it's decompressed to `inflate.onData`. Provide what you have using `inflate.push(stuff, false)`. Then use `inflate.onData` to accumulate the bytes as they're generated.